# Find databases that are linked to my SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dblink

I am preparing for a change to the IP address of my SQL Server, and I know how to find all the database links from my server in SSMS. But how can I determine which databases (if any) have a one-directional link connecting to my server?

Comment: Shouldn't you be connecting by server name instead of IP anyway? But I don't understand what you are asking here.

Comment: If all of you connections are connecting to the SQL Server Name, DNS will handle the IP change. If there are connections via IP Address, see who screams the loudest when you change it and see what jobs fail as well.